# Вопрос по оптимизации куска кода

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Как и вообще возможно ли оптимизировать данный участок кода?

```
string[] str = { solution, answer };
richTextBox1.Lines = str;
richTextBox1.Select(0, str[0].Length);
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Properties.Settings.Default.FontColor;
richTextBox1.Select(str[0].Length, str[1].Length + 1);
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь с [политикой относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)

Comment: А что вас смущает в этом коде?

Comment: @andreycha, меня, например, смущает использование `str[0]`, `str[1]` когда можно было использовать `solution`, `answer` :)

Comment: А что за волшебная +1 в предпоследней строке? догадываюсь, но если я прав, лучше сделать немного по-другому. В чем требуется оптимизация?

Comment: А какого рода оптимизация вас интересует? Что происходит не так и какого измеримого эффекта вы хотите добиться?